# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$

Tags: java, gradle, java-11

I'm trying to build the application with Java SE 11 and Gradle 7.0, and it builds using the IDE however when I try to build it using the terminal I get this error. How can I fix it.

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x1d7a8227) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x1d7a8227
```

Comment: I encountered the same with Java version `openjdk 17.0.1 2021-10-19`. Downgrading to version `openjdk 11.0.13 2021-10-19 LTS` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Downgrading from open jdk 17 to 11 worked for me.

Answer (score 40):

It took me up to 3 working days and I found a simple solution. Go to `android/gradle.properties`
change `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M` to

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: does not seem to be working here

Comment: It work for me.         a complete configuration :  org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED

Comment: this has worked for me, but can you share any resources to check the details?

Comment: it works on Flamigo 2022

Comment: it work for me and I was downgrade from jdk 20 to 17

Answer (score 17):

Resolved it by recreating the project from existing sources & updating the `.gradle-wrapper.properties` version to 7.3.2

Location: `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.2-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Comment: I checked https://gradle.org/releases/ and found the latest version, which worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

I resolved upgrading the gradle version with this:

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 7.5
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same error. To get around it, I ended up setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable before running gradle from the command line, and also added it to my path.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home 
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

openjdk-11 worked fine for me, but you want to make sure your JAVA_HOME environment variable points to an actual location before setting it. This may vary based on your OS.

Answer (score 3):

You need to downgrade your java version to JDK 11 version.
For Mac OS Users Follow below Steps:

1. Check the Java version's already installed and see if jdk11 is installed or not, if not, install it first.

> /usr/libexec/java_home -V

2. Open vim ~/.zshrc
3. Add the below line , note update your JDK name properly below

> export
> JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<<Your_JDK_11_version>>/Contents/Home

4. Restart the terminal
5. Check Java Version

> java -version

Answer (score 2):

I had to upgrade my gradle file to 7.3.1 and add this line in gradle.properties in android directory
`org.gradle.jvmargs=--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED`

The gradle upgrade is required for Java 17 support

Answer (score 1):

### for flutter run this command may be your issue resolve

```
rm -r ~/.pub-cache
rm -r ./pubspec.lock
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter pub cache clean
flutter pub cache repair
flutter precache
dart pub upgrade
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Answer (score 1):

I used [jdk 11.0.13](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/) version and it works well.

This is my ~/.bash_profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.13.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue.
When I was running in intellij terminal ./gradlew build war this exception happened.

I saw the problem is terminal java version. In terminal is 17 and my application is running in 11.

I solve my problem creating war file by intellij, but there is some missing environment configuration to fix in my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

works for me by updating compile and testCompile to implementation and testImplementation, and upgrade gradle to 7.+