# react-native-community_netinfo:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: react-native

**When running npx react-native run-android it shows this error. I am using JDK 17 and gradle 6.8.1**

```
> Task :react-native-community_netinfo:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

> Task :react-native-community_masked-view:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

> Task :react-native-community_datetimepicker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

> Task :react-native-community_cameraroll:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

> Task :react-native-extra-dimensions-android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

> Task :react-native-camera:compileGeneralDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED


warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: C:\reactapp\ehs_pulse_app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cameraroll\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\cameraroll\CameraRollModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: C:\reactapp\ehs_pulse_app\node_modules\@react-native-async-storage\async-storage\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\asyncstorage\AsyncStorageModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: C:\reactapp\ehs_pulse_app\node_modules\react-native-extra-dimensions-android\android\src\main\java\ca\jaysoo\extradimensions\ExtraDimensionsModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 warnings

FAILURE: Build completed with 7 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_netinfo:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x7471177c) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x7471177c

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_masked-view:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x7471177c) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x7471177c

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_datetimepicker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x7471177c) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x7471177c

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

4: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_cameraroll:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x7471177c) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x7471177c

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

5: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x7471177c) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x7471177c

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

6: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-extra-dimensions-android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x7471177c) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x7471177c

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

7: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-camera:compileGeneralDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x7471177c) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x7471177c
```

**and if I use JDK 11 in running the project it will install but it will suddenly crash after the message says 'BUILD SUCCESFUL'.**

also if I use JDK 11 and run 'npx react-native doctor' it will show that it can't find the sdk but if I use JDK 17 it will be just fine.

I am trying to run this old project.

Comment: One of your errors seems very similar to the one from this question: [java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70423297).  You might try some of the answers from there to see if they help.

Comment: That being said, absent a [mcve] that allows others to reproduce your problem, as suggested by [ask], it's unlikely you will get a definitive answer.  Is there any chance you could [edit] your question to share enough details for us to reproduce your problem?  As it is, your post is mainly just an extended error log with no way to reproduce the errors.